# Remove UserId from ConfirmEmail action and implement a check on every page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-identity

I would like to remove the `UserId` query-string from the `ConfirmEmail` action in the `AccountController`, as I do not want `UserId`'s to be sent in email messages.

Once I do this, I will still need to obtain the `UserId` in order to call the method `UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync`. In order to do this, I plan to require authentication for the `ConfirmEmail` action. This way I can call `User.Identity.GetUserId()` to obtain the `UserId` parameter needed to confirm the email address.

Upon logging in, if the user's email address is not confirmed, they will be redirected to the `ConfirmEmail` page. Additionally, I would like to implement a check on every page load to see if the user's email is confirmed and if it isn't I would like them to be redirected to the `ConfirmEmail` page.

My questions are as follows:

1. How would I go about implementing this check on every page?
2. Would there be a large performance penalty on checking if a user's email is confirmed on every page? If so, would it be better to store the confirmed value in a session variable and check that instead?
3. If I do end up using a session variable can it easily be removed or changed by a user?
4. Am I on the completely wrong track? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I go about implementing this check on every page?

You can use [action filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) for fulfilling this purpose. They work like charm with Method enter and Method exit strategy by simple applying attribute on the Action methods like AOP(Aspect oriented programming).

> Would there be a large performance penalty on checking if a user's email is confirmed on every page? If so, would it be better to store the confirmed value in a session variable and check that instead?

It depends on how you implement it and how much is the cost of checking operation. Keeping information in session is alwasy an easy idea but it's not a good practice comes in picture later when you go for scaling the application across servers. Then you come back with session and types of session and what information should I store in session. So it again depends on various scenarios.

You can keep this infomration as simple flag in a cookie. Then you can create an action filter that would check for the cookie if it request has that information as e.g. "Not yet confirmed". If not just ignore it. you can invalidate the cookie once the user has confirmed the email address.

Comment: Thank you for this I will read up on action filters and try to implement it as you said. The documentation you sent is from 2008, is it still relevant to MVC 5? Also, how do you create a flag in a cookie? Isn't it the same as creating a session variable?

Comment: Behavior of ActionFilters would be same in MVC5 too. Though we have more type of Filter other Actions in MVC5 e.g. AuthencticationFilter etc. Session variable would remain on the server and if you have sticky session then its ok to use session variable otherwise load balancer could redirect coming request to another server which might not have information of Session variable that was created on first one. Cookies give easy solution and they come and go with each reqeust/response.

Comment: I tried implementing the action filter, however my session variable appears to be null on the filter. On login I have this `Session["ConfirmEmail"] = "true";` and on the filter I have `if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["ConfirmEmail"] != null)`