# Session variable becomes null in action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, session-variables

I am trying to create an action filter to redirect a user to the `ConfirmEmail` action if a user has an unconfirmed email address. In my controller I set the session variable, and in my action filter I check to see if the session variable is null or not.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    { 
          // some code here

          if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
          {
            Session["ConfirmEmail"] = "true";
          }

         // some code here
     }

    public class ConfirmEmailFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {    
          public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
                {
                    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["ConfirmEmail"] != null)
                    {
                       if (!(bool)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["ConfirmEmail"])
                       {
                        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                            new RouteValueDictionary
                            {
                                {"controller", "Account"},
                                {"action", "ConfirmEmail"}
                            });
                        }
                    }
                 }
      }
```

I am unsure as to why the the session cannot be read by the action filter. Is there another method I should be using to implement this check?

**Edit**

I found the Issue! In my code (before I set the session I have the following) 
`Session.Clear();` `Session.Abandon();`. I didn't think that this would be an issue since it is called before I set my session but I guess it is

Comment: As a wild stab in the dark, does changing the if statement to: `if (!await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id).ConfigureAwait(false))` work?

Comment: I know that my if statement is not an issue because when I debugged I saw that it made it into the if statement and that `Session["ConfirmEmail"]` was in fact equal to true. However, once it went to my filter class, the `filterContext.HttpContext.Session["ConfirmEmail"]` was false

Comment: @EitanK - was `false` or `"false"`? You set the session variable to string `"true"`, but expect the type cast `(bool)Session[...]` to work - it won't. You need to either set the variable to boolean value `true` or do the conversion with `System.Convert.ToBoolean(...)`.

Comment: @Igor i fixed that part thanks. However, it never gets to that point because the action filter thinks that `Session["ConfirmEmai"]` is null

Comment: Have you tried just putting something in session in the controller, and reading it back in the action filter, without any more logic (no if or cast)? Maye you have to put `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Required)]` on your controller

Comment: @Johnny5 I tried what you said and it didn't work.

Comment: Action filters are designed to be used for cross-cutting concerns, such as logging, auditing, or authorization. I don't see how creating an action filter for such a task benefits you. You could easily do the confirm email check within your action method and you wouldn't need to use session state at all.

Comment: @NightOwl888 the point of this is so that I could remove `UserId` from the `ConfirmEmail` action. In order to do this I have to require authentication on that action and check on every page_load whether or not a user's email is authenticated. Please see this post to see what I am trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383200/remove-userid-from-confirmemail-action-and-implement-a-check-on-every-page-load

Comment: @EitanK - User is a property of the controller class itself. MVC already keeps track of the `UserName` for you as well as whether the user is logged in. There is no need to make a `userId` parameter on the action method.

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is a little off

1. Try passing over a boolean value rather that the string value "true"

   ```
       public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
       {
           if (!await UserManager<>.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id))
           {
               Session["ConfirmEmail"] = true;
               RedirectToAction("ConfirmEmail");
           }
       }
   ```
2. Your OnActionExecuting should be using the protected access modifier
3. Your if statement is checking if !true instead of just checking true

   ```
   protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
       if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["ConfirmEmail"] != null)
       {
           if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session["ConfirmEmail"] is bool && (bool) filterContext.HttpContext.Session["ConfirmEmail"])
           {
               filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                   new RouteValueDictionary
                   {
                       {"controller", "Account"},
                       {"action", "ConfirmEmail"}
                   });
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue is that whatever value is passed whether it be a string or bool becomes null the moment the debugger gets to my filter class. So it doesn't even make it to the second if statement in the `OnActionExecuting` method. Additionally when I change the access to protected I get this error message : `cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuting`